# Blurred text in the TStatusBar control

Tags: windows, delphi, statusbar, vcl, text-rendering

I have for a very long time experienced a hugely annoying problem with the `TStatusBar` VCL control, a thin wrapper around the Win32 [status bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/desktop/Controls/status-bars) control.

Since this appears to me as a very common and frustrating issue, I am very surprised Google (and StackOverflow) doesn't seem to know much about it.

The problem is that the status bar text becomes very blurred when it hasn't changed for a while; the precise conditions are still unknown to me. But I see this every day:

[image: Screenshot of blurred status bar]

If one of the panels has its text updated, the new text is rendered correctly (see last panel):

[image: Screenshot of partially blurred status bar]

Is this something that only happens when I am in the vicinity of running Delphi processes, or is it indeed a known issue? More importantly, is there a known cure? (And, academically, why does this happen? It wouldn't surprise me if it is related to transparent drawing of anti-aliased text by code originally designed for unthemed Win9x.)

I have tried to enable double-buffering, but I am not sure if that completely resolves the issue. (I have seen even worse behaviour in non-double-buffered list view controls, which is resolved by making them double-buffered.)

Comment: Andreas, what do you mean under *when it hasn't changed for a while*?

Comment: @Dima: I actually don't know exactly when this problem occurs. Typically I see this blurred text when I go back working with a window I haven't touched for a few minutes or hours. If the statusbar text is changed in a panel, the newly changed text is always displayed correctly.

Comment: Andreas, I compiled simple project with `TStatusBar` control only and run it. There is no such a *blurred* text. I work on Win7 with enabled Aero. Even without Aero there is no problem with this control.  I also sized window, minimize it and placed it far away off screen, but cannot reproduce behaviour you have described.

Comment: By the way, Andreas, what version of OS do you use? I canno detect it myself from your screenshot. Is it Win10? Another one guess - probably your `Delphi` is newer than my and in the first one something related with `TStatusBar` drawing has been changed? I use Delphi Starter 10.2.

Comment: It is hard to reproduce when you try, since the problem doesn't show until after quite a few minutes of very little provocation (in fact, the more you provoke the window, the less chance of seeing the issue). I use Windows 7 at home and Windows 10 at work, and I suspect the problem is much worse in Windows 10. I use Delphi 10.2 both at home and at work.

Comment: Andreas, I still have my simple project running, and still there is no problem. Well if it is very important for you, you could owner-draw panels of `TStatusBar` yourself. It will involve additional work (as you should check whenever new panel has been added and set its style to owner-draw), but this problem will be solved (I suppose). I believe there are lots of users who, perhaps, already have a solution for your case and they would be very kind to show it us.

Comment: Andreas I can reproduce this under Win7! Steps to do this (Aero must be enabled): run application; disable Aero; enable Aero. Effect is the same as on your screenshot. But setting `DoubleBuffered` property to `True` allows to avoid this - text draw correctly.

Comment: Dima: Great, thanks! :) I very seldom perform that sequence of operations, but still observes blurry status-bar texts every day, so probably the underlying issue manifests itself under different circumstances as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made all status bars in my applications double-buffered a week ago, and I haven't seen any blurred text in any of them since then. Previously, I saw severely blurred text daily. Hence, it seems like this issue - whatever is causing it - can be fixed by making the status bars double buffered.